Inconsistent width of relational operators in newtxmath
I recently changed from txfonts to newtx because it is said to have more consistent spacing and sizing. (And indeed, I find delimiters are handled significantly better in newtx.)
However, I came across an issue today that is so striking that I cannot believed that it has been overlooked so far: Apparently the binary relational operators =, \leq, and < all have different widths. Or something in the spacing around the actual symbols is wrong.
Here is a minimal example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
$|=|$

$|\leq|$

$|<|$
\end{document}

And this is a screenshot of what pdflatex from the most recent MacTeX distributions makes of it:

As you can see, the width difference between = and \leq is most striking. But the widths of \leq and < do not match, either. Both computer modern and txfonts do not seem to have this problem.
So, is there an external fix for this already? (I would say that I already did my due diligence to obtain the most recent version of newtx by installing the newest MacTeX release.)

The symbols =, \leq, and < are relational, not binary, operators.

Good point. I changed the title. (However, the binary operators + and -  have different widths, too.)

Update 29 August 2024
Version 1.753 of NewTX has fixed the issue
Original answer
That's very interesting and it should be fixed.
The widest symbol is \leq. Possible solutions could be acting on the sidebearings of \leq and <.
Here I choose to widen =, < and >.
First I measure and check:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{$|\mspace{0.936mu}=\mspace{0.936mu}|$}\the\wd0\ 
\sbox0{$|\leq|$}\the\wd0\ 

\sbox0{$|\mspace{0.153mu}<\mspace{0.153mu}|$}\the\wd0\ 
\sbox0{$|\mspace{0.153mu}>\mspace{0.153mu}|$}\the\wd0

$|\mspace{0.936mu}=\mspace{0.936mu}|$

$|\leq|$

$|\mspace{0.153mu}<\mspace{0.153mu}|$

\makebox[0pt][l]{\textcolor{red}{$\mspace{0.153mu}<$}}$\leq$

\makebox[0pt][l]{\textcolor{red}{$\mspace{0.153mu}>$}}$\leq$

\makebox[0pt][l]{\textcolor{red}{$\mspace{0.936mu}=$}}$\leq$


\end{document}


The difference of 0.00002pt` is negligible.
Then we can make =, < and > math active, adding the spaces.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathchardef\standardeq=\mathcode`=
  \mathchardef\standardless=\mathcode`<
  \mathchardef\standardgreater=\mathcode`>
  \mathcode`="8000
  \mathcode`<"8000
  \mathcode`>"8000
}
\begingroup\lccode`~`=\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def~}{\mathrel{\mspace{0.936mu}\standardeq\mspace{0.936mu}}}
\begingroup\lccode`~`<\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def~}{\mathrel{\mspace{0.153mu}\standardless\mspace{0.153mu}}}
\begingroup\lccode`~`>\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def~}{\mathrel{\mspace{0.153mu}\standardgreater\mspace{0.153mu}}}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{$|=|$}\the\wd0\ 
\sbox0{$|\leq|$}\the\wd0\ 

\sbox0{$|<|$}\the\wd0\ 
\sbox0{$|>|$}\the\wd0

$|=|$

$|\leq|$

$|<|$

\makebox[0pt][l]{\textcolor{red}{$<$}}$\leq$

\makebox[0pt][l]{\textcolor{red}{$>$}}$\leq$

\makebox[0pt][l]{\textcolor{red}{$=$}}$\leq$


\end{document}



Actually, there should be some fix for the other math styles.

Maybe this should be reported to the package author?

Yes, I have already notified the author Michael Sharpe via email.
